# Laravel set first Bootstrap banner as Active

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap, laravel

I'm currently trying to loop through a bunch of banners saved on a database and I need to set the first banner as active. I've tried if($banner->first) {{ 'active' }} endif, but this doesn't seem to work for me as all items get set as active. I thought about setting the id to 1, but that would break if someone deleted the image with that id. Here's my code so far...

Controller:

```
public function index()
{
    //
    $banners = Banner::all();
    $pages = Page::all();

    return View::make('page')->with('banners', $banners, 'pages', $pages);
}
```

View:

```
<div id="mainCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        @foreach($banners as $banner)
                <div class="item @if($banner->first()) {{ 'active' }} @endif">
                    <img style="width: 100%; height: 500px" src="{{ $banner->image }}" alt="{{ $banner->alt }}">
                </div>
        @endforeach
    </div>

    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#mainCarousel" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#mainCarousel" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
    </a>
</div>
```

I have also tried $banners->first() as well as $banner->first() and get the same result.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

m4tthumphrey gave me the correct answer on the Laravel IRC chat. So if anyone else gets this problem, I will give you the correct answer here.

I think this is pretty self explanatory, but Laravel will basically find the first ID of the first banner in your database and match the id to that.

```
@if($banner->id === $banner->first()->id) {{ 'active' }} @endif
```

I've just found out this isn't the best solution if you have different banners for different pages, if that's the case then try.

`@foreach($banners as $index => $banner)
    <div class="item @if($index == 0) {{ 'active' }} @endif">
    <img style="width: 100%;" src="{{ $banner->image }}" alt="{{ $banner->alt }}">
    </div>
@endforeach`

Comment: Your first solution worked for me, whereas the second did not. Thanks!  (First solution = @if($banner->id === $banner->first()->id) {{ 'active' }} @endif )